# Using R to calculate percent time above threshold with imputation

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling, imputation

The data frame has 5 columns, namely, `ID`, `index_date`, `last_date`, `measure_date`, and `measurement` such that each `ID` has only one `index_date` and `last_date` but multiple `measure_date`s:

```
set.seed(0)

library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tibble(
  ID = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,2)),
  index_date = as.Date(c(rep("2020-01-01",3), rep("2021-04-13",2))),
  last_date = as.Date(c(rep("2021-02-18",3), rep("2022-12-30",2))),
  measure_date = as.Date(c("2020-02-03","2020-05-30","2021-01-04",
                           "2021-06-20","2022-06-06")),
  measurement = runif(5))

# A tibble: 5 × 5
     ID index_date last_date  measure_date measurement
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>             <dbl>
1     1 2020-01-01 2021-02-18 2020-02-03         0.897
2     1 2020-01-01 2021-02-18 2020-05-30         0.266
3     1 2020-01-01 2021-02-18 2021-01-04         0.372
4     2 2021-04-13 2022-12-30 2021-06-20         0.573
5     2 2021-04-13 2022-12-30 2022-06-06         0.908
```

All `measure_date`s are between `index_date` and `last_date` for a given `ID`.

How could I calculate the the percent of days for a given `ID` when `measurement` was above certain threshold (say 0.5 for the toy `df` above) such that:

1. values between `index_date` and the first `measure_date` are imputed by first observation carried backwards,
2. values between last `measure_date` and `last_date` are imputed by last observation carried forward, and
3. values between `measure_date`s are imputed using linear interpolation?

This is a typical scenario in epidemiology studies. There's a not so cool way of expanding all the dates and manually imputing the `measurement`s by using `mutate()` and `case_when()` but th original data frame has more than 100K `ID`s and dates range over several years. Soon enough the manual approach becomes impractical due to memory-hogging nature of the task.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: With the given example what would be the expected output?

Comment: For every ID, there will be a number between 0 and 1 representing percent days that ID had their measurements greater than threshold post-imputation. Actual answer for the given example will vary owing to the stochastic output of `runif()`. I will rerun the above example with set.seed and update. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @VivekVerma I added seed to question

Comment: @VivekVerma - so just to clarify, re: "There's a not so cool way of expanding all the dates and manually imputing the measurements by using mutate() and case_when()" - are you not wanting a dplyr solution? What sort of solution are you wanting?

Answer (score 0):

```
threshold_days <- function(df) {
  # first, make sure the dates are in order
  df <- df |> arrange(ID, measure_date)

  # second, find the number of days between the beginning and the end for each ID
  total <- summarise(df, total = as.integer(last_date[1] - index_date[1]), .by = ID)
  
# next, find the number of days above 0.5 for both from the last measurement date to the end, and from the start to the first measurement date
  ends <- df |> 
    summarise(s = (measurement[1] > 0.5) * as.integer(measure_date[1] - index_date[1]),
              e = (last(measurement) > 0.5) * as.integer(last(last_date) - last(measure_date)), .by = ID) |> 
    pivot_longer(c(s, e)) |> 
    summarise(days = sum(value), .by = ID)

  # find the number of days measurement stays above 0.5 
  df |> 
    mutate(mpd = ifelse(measurement <= 0.5 & lead(measurement) <=0.5, 
                        0, 
                        abs(measurement - lead(measurement))/abs(as.integer(measure_date - lead(measure_date)))),
           days = ifelse(mpd == 0, 
                         0, 
                         (pmax(measurement, lead(measurement) - 0.5)/mpd)), 
           .by = ID) |> 
    summarise(days = sum(days, na.rm = TRUE), .by = ID) |> 
    # add on the ends
    add_row(ends) |> 
    summarise(days = sum(days), .by = ID) |> 
    left_join(total, by = "ID") |>
    mutate(percentage = days/total * 100)
}
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
     ID  days total percentage
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
1     1  199.   414       48.1
2     2  875.   626      140.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Expand the data frame to include all dates for each ID
df <- df |> 
  group_by(person_id) |> 
  mutate(first_biomarker_measurement_date = min(biomarker_measurement_date),
         last_biomarker_measurement_date = max(biomarker_measurement_date)) |> 
  complete(biomarker_measurement_date = seq(idx_date[1], last_date[1], by = "day")) |> 
  mutate(biomarker_value1 = biomarker_value) |> 
  fill(all_of(c("person_id", "idx_date", "last_date", 
                "first_biomarker_measurement_date", "biomarker_value1",
                "last_biomarker_measurement_date")), .direction = "downup") |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  # FOCB and LOCF imputation
  mutate(biomarker_value2 = if_else((biomarker_measurement_date < first_biomarker_measurement_date & 
                              is.na(biomarker_value)) |
                             (biomarker_measurement_date > last_biomarker_measurement_date & 
                                is.na(biomarker_value)), 
                           biomarker_value1, biomarker_value))
# Linear interpolation to impute values between biomarker_measurement_dates
df <- df |>  
  group_by(person_id) |> 
  mutate(biomarker_value3 = zoo::na.approx(biomarker_value2))
# Calculate the percent of days when biomarker_value was above the threshold
df <- df |> 
  group_by(person_id) |> 
  mutate(percent_days_above_threshold = 
           sum(biomarker_value3 > biomarker_threshold) / n()) |> 
  select(person_id, percent_days_above_threshold) |> 
  distinct() |> ungroup()
```